# asyncio: how to combine sync code without forcing full exposure to asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

It seems that python's asyncio is an all-or-nothing kind of deal. Specifically it seems to force full call stack to be async-aware.

Here is an example:

Let's assume that there is an algorithm implemented by function *a()*.
That algorithm calls function *b()*.

```
def a(b):
  for i in ...:
    # do smth...
    res = b()
    # do smth more ...
```

Now let's assume that function *b()* might be implemented differently in different environments and one might want to call *a()* inside an async event loop (with *loop.call_soon()*) with *b()* calling some asyncio-aware code:

```
def b():
   await .... # this forces b() to be declared async.
```

Using existing event loop seems to be explicitly prohibited...
So, are there methods to implement this functionality without forcing the full stack (*a()* and *b()*) to be explicitly defined as async coroutines?

Comment: `It seems that python's asyncio is an all-or-nothing kind of deal. Specifically it seems to force full call stack to be async-aware.` -- Yep.  All `async` stacks are like that.

Comment: Gevent offers a little more flexibility.  What I like about it, is you don't have to necessarily write async code to make it async.  Especially WSGI stuff.  A simple spawn is all that's required to make it async.

Comment: [`run_in_executor`](https://colmap.github.io/index.html)?

Answer (score 6):

Although taken at face value asyncio *is* an all-or-nothing deal, there are still two escape hatches that can help when dealing with legacy or heterogenous environment:

- Within asyncio, you can await [`loop.run_in_executor(callable, args...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executing-code-in-thread-or-process-pools) to evaluate sync code in another thread, suspending the current coroutine until the result is ready.
- Outside asyncio, you can use [`asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe) to submit a coroutine to an event loop running in another thread. It immediately returns returns a [`concurrent.futures` future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) which has a blocking `result()` method that blocks the current thread without adversely affecting the event loop. (The use of `run_coroutine_threadsafe` requires starting an event loop in a dedicated thread beforehand.)

With those two tools at your disposal, it is not that hard to mix asyncio and classic synchronous code.